# MYSQL group by particular behavior

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if you can do this in mysql.

TABLE

```
| F1  |  F2  |
--------------
|  a  |  b   |
|  a  |  b   |
|  a  |  c   |
|  a  |  c   |
|  a  |  c   |
```

How could I do the group by clause to accomplish this?

```
| F1  |  F2  |
--------------
|  a  |  b   |
|  a  |  c   |
```

Thanks

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT f1,f2 FROM my_table; This is very basic stuff. Suggest you borrow a book or read a tutorial or something before going any further.

Comment: You asked, "I would like to know if you can do this in mysql."  Yes! "How could I do the group by clause to accomplish this?," `GROUP BY F1, F2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT f1, f2
FROM test_table
GROUP BY f1, f2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT F1, F2
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY F1, F2
```

Though since F1 is always A in this case I suppose this would work (but I don't like using mysql extensions)

```
SELECT F1, F2
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY F2
```